# jQuery Click on Embed not Working?

Tags: jquery, embed

I have the following jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uShjA/ - and I am trying to do something like

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'embed', function () {
     alert('clicked');
});
```

i.e. do something when a user clicks on an `Embed` element - however it seems [in Chrome] that this doesn't work at all ?

Comment: if the embedded element is a flash element it might have something to do with chromes custom flash integration?

Comment: I don't see it working in FF either.  The video starts and stops, but no alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be don't with embed because:

> As of jQuery 1.4 we can no longer attach data (and thus, events) to object, embed, or applet elements because critical errors occur when attaching data to Java applets.

The source is [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), about half way down the page (just search for 'embed').

Comment: yeah what I have above is exactly that

Comment: `live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 (and unnecessary since 1.4.3 when `delegate` was added). `on` should be used instead, as the OP is doing.

Comment: well I have a corrected answer anyway (but thanks for telling me about .live())

Comment: hmm strange - that might be answer, but I'm surprised that they removed this to `.on()`. thanks none of the less

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking the flash player and not an html element. JQuery 1.4+ cannot track events on add-ons. I hope I got your question correctly. If not, then please correct me :)